# Conda prompt command not working after installing keras

Tags: python, keras, anaconda, data-science, miniconda

i download keras on miniconda by using *conda install -c conda-forge keras* command .And it got successfully completed.But after that when i opened the conda prompt command,it shows following error-

```
 C:\Users\Administrator>python           
 C:\Users\Administrator\Miniconda3\etc\keras\load_config.py  1>temp.txt

 C:\Users\Administrator>set /p KERAS_BACKEND= 0<temp.txt

 C:\Users\Administrator>del temp.txt

 C:\Users\Administrator>python -c "import keras"  1>nul 2>&1
```

after 10 sec  it collapsed and closed.

i have no clue what to do. i gave effort and time to set up environment and install packages.please help.

Comment: The code does not look like an error.

Comment: yeah but that what creating the problem